# Why XHR finished loading: POST "http://127.0.0.1:8000/broadcasting/auth" appears only after I hit refresh?

Tags: laravel

I check if user can join the presenceChannel.

```
Broadcast::channel('chat', function ($user) {
  if(auth()->check())
     return $user;
});
```

On my target page I see error

POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/broadcasting/auth 403 (Forbidden)

The user shows up on the page only when I hit refresh. Help me understand  why this is happening.

Component

```
<script>
  export default { 
     data() {
        return {
           users:[],  
      }    
   },   

    mounted() {
        window.Echo.join('chat')
                   .here(users => (this.users = users));
    },  
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can now check for logged-in users

```
if (Auth::check()) {
    return $user;
}
```